# Listeners and Cookies in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I try to use setcookie in Laravel listeners with queue, setcookie return true but the problem is in `chrome (Or Firefox) DevTools> Application> Cookies` cookies are not set and not working.

My Class:

```php
class FlarumEventSubscriber implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function onUserLogin($event)
    {
        $user = $event->user;
        $response = $this->authenticate($user->mobile, $user->password);
        $token = $response['token'] ?: '';
        setcookie('flarum_session', $token, time() + 99999999 ,  '/', 'localhost'); // ======> The problem
    }
    public function subscribe($events)
    {
        $events->listen(
            'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login',
            'App\Listeners\FlarumEventSubscriber@onUserLogin'
        );
    }

    private function authenticate($id, $password)
    {
        $endpoint = '/api/token';
        $method = 'POST';

        $data = [
            'identification' => $id,
            'password' => $password,
            'lifetime' => 99999999
        ];

        return $this->sendRequest($endpoint, $method, $data);
    }
}
```

EventServiceProvider :

```php
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**flarum subscriber */
    protected $subscribe = [
        'App\Listeners\FlarumEventSubscriber',
    ];
}
```

In `FlarumEventSubscriber` class, I send a request after the user login to Laravel, and after that, some information needs to be stored in the cookie.

**My efforts:**

Use `Cookie::queue()` instead of `setcookie()` => Not working

Test on other domains => Not working

**Info:**

```
PHP v7.4.26
Laravel 8.0
Wampserver v3.2.6 64bit
```

Comment: you are setting the cookie in the queue, meaning this is a PHP CLI process. Cookies are stored on the browser. 

Why would you handle the user session in a queue?

Comment: If you are on a local environment, make sure to set `secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false) ` in your config/session.php file in order to use cookie.